# Get sibling's name attribute, use it to adjust value of element with equivalent ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up a system such that when a button is clicked, the value of an input field is adjusted.

The ID of the field to be adjusted is equal to the name of the sibling element of the button.

As such, I'm attempting to code:
On button click
 - Get sibling's name
 - Get element with ID equal to siblings name
 - Change value of that element

Here is my attempt:

```
$(function() {
    $('#values').on('click', '.remField', function() {                      
        var = $(this).siblings().name()
        $('#var').val('DELETE');
        return false;
    });
});
```

However this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector creation and retrieval of name is incorrect try:

```
 $('#values').on('click', '.remField', function() {                      
        var name = $(this).siblings().attr('name');
        $('#' + name).val('DELETE');
        return false;
    });
```

Note that `siblings` may return multiple items as a collection and `attr` on a collection will get the name of the 1st item in the collection. If you know it is the next of prev element then better use `.next()` or `.prev()` to be more specific. `var` is a keyword you can't use that as a variable name.

Comment: It's 2.37am here and I've been working on this project and related problems for 15 hours straight: you have no idea how grateful I am right now for you fixing this so quickly and easily. Works perfectly - thanks! :D

Comment: oh and thanks for the note on other siblings they are the only two elements that are children of their parent div so is ok! but good note

Answer (score 0):

Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#values').on('click', '.remField', function () {
    var name = $(this).siblings().attr('name');
    $('#' + name).val('DELETE');
    return false;
});
```

---

[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) will return multiple items